# Upload Image From iPhone to WCF Service

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, wcf

I'm trying to build an iPhone app and c# WCF Service to upload an image to a SQL Service database.

I've got my app breaking an image down to NSData and posting off to a WCF Service using the following code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 90);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/ImageDiaryService.svc/json/AddMediaItem"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Test" forKey:@"Name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Test description." forKey:@"Description"];
[request setPostValue:@"JPEG" forKey:@"ImageType"];
[request setPostValue:@"iPhone" forKey:@"MediaType"];

[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"ImageData"];

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

The problem I'm having is with the web service. I'm not sure what type of data I should be receiving from the app POST. I've tried receiving it as an a byte array but that didn't working.

My WCF Service is a REST service.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try receiving it as a Stream. The blog post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx shows how to receive arbitrary data in a WCF REST service.

Comment: If I receive the image via a Stream, am I able to post a Data Contract to the service? I read on your post that the Stream parameter has to be the the only parameter passed via the post body?

Comment: No, you wouldn't receive it as a data contract, but if you really want a data contract, then you'd need to encode the image in a format for which data contracts can be created (XML or JSON). In both cases there would be some perf hit (on XML you'd need to base64-encode the image, on JSON it's even worse, as byte[] values are represented as arrays of integers). Why do you need to pass a data contract for this operation (you only need to pass the file contents? For other operations in the service you can still use data contracts if you want.

Comment: I need to upload an image along with some other parameters (name, description, source, image type etc). What would you suggest is the best way to handle this? I suppose I could create two methods, one to upload the image and another to upload the data but then would it faster to do it using Base64 compared to doing two posts to my service?

Comment: If all those parameters are strings (which they seem to be) you can pass them in the URI, something along the lines of [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/AddMediaItem?name={name},desc={description}"] void Upload(Stream contents, string name, string description);

Comment: Or you can also pass those parameters as HTTP headers, and use WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers in the service to retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, of the two, does it matter which? Parameters like the name and description will have spaces and potentially special characters so would it be wise to pass through the URL?

Comment: Passing parameters with spaces / non-ASCII characters in the URL shouldn't be a problem, as long as the URL is correctly encoded (i.e., ' ' == '%20'). As far as which one, I'd usually use the first option (parameters in the URI), since it is explicit in the operation signature which inputs it takes, but that's my preference.