# How to decode Post Request in WCF coming from iPhone?

Tags: wcf, rest, ios5, streaming, datacontract

I asked this question couple of times, and I have yet to be given a good answer. May be I am doing this wrong. I would like to send one Http Post request containing some text parameters and an image.
in iPhone:

```
NSString reqstr = "param1=val1&param2=val2&..."
NSData *strData = [str DataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //parameters
NSData *imageData = [NSData NSJPEGRepresenation(myImage.jpg,1)]; //image
NSMutableData *body = ...;
body.appendData = strData;
body.appendData = imageData;
req.setHttpBody = body;
```

In WCF:

```
void postData(Stream strm)
{
  //strm contains "param1=val1&param2=val2.....image raw binary here..........."
}

[DataContract]
class Employee { string param1,string param2, Stream photo..}
```

- Is this the correct way of sending such an object? Is this not common between iphone and WCF?
- How do I parse the bytes in the stream to read params especially to form the image from the binary data. Note If it was image byitself, I know how to do it. How do I get it out of the stream with other parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF requires opt-In serialization, so tagging a class with [DataContract] is not enough to serialize any of it's members, any member you want serialized must also be tagged with [DataMember]. Also, there's no reason for you to send the stream itself, you should be able to do something like this instead:

```
[DataContract]
class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    string param1;

    [DataMember]
    string param2;

    [DataMember]
    JPEG image;
}

//Within your service, the postData contract will accept an Employee object from the caller // and perform some logic on it in the service.

void postData(Employee emp)
{
    //Do something with emp
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or if this is more of the same advice you've already gotten.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have service contract like yours. I am a bit confused, Does Employee also have to have [Serializable] attribute. Also, if I receive emp object in my PostData method, is this binary, how do I read it after to get my members out of it? I guess I am not sure how to go forward.

Comment: @software2007 Employee doesn't need the [Serializable] attribute, that's actually the .Net opt-out version of WCF's [DataContract] attribute. You're better off using [DataContract] b/c it gives you more control. By the time the data hits your PostData method it will have already been deserialized into an Employee object, so you'll be able to work with that directly. This is if you're using WCF on both sides, so please let me know if that isn't the case.

Comment: One side is iphone which will be sending stream of bytes (original post). The stream will have parameters and raw binary data representation of the image. The WCF has to read this stream and turn into back into data like parameters and an image.

Comment: got it, so the iPhone has no knowledge of the Employee object. In that case take a look at how it's performed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6011595/941243

Comment: Thanks, the link is more helpful because I have same exact problem. I could pass the text as header and stream as body. I am not sure what I would have to do if I needed to send multiple photos instead of one.